# How to order ls command display in numerical order?

Tags: bash, ls

I created 3 files in a directory with the following names:

`11 13 9`

Problem, as I created file `9` after `13` it is placed after file `13` when I do the `ls` command.

Do you have any idea to make the `ls` command sort the files in the numerical order, like this:

`9 11 13`

Comment: `ls|sort -n` (but this will list them on multiple lines)

Comment: You can use `sort -n` to sort in numerical order but I'm concerned what you're planning on doing next...

Comment: Check out my answer below. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 21):

Look at the `man` page for `ls`.
From there-

> -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text.

You'll find that the command `ls -v`  does what you want.

If you want the file names on different lines then you can do `ls -1v`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ls -v` on macOS and FreeBSD does not perform a natural sort on the list of files. FreeBSD ls does not support this flag at all. On macOS it can be used to

> force unedited printing of non-graphic characters; this is the default when output is not to a terminal.

If you badly need the GNU extension of `-v` to the ls utility, you can install the GNU ls and then use `alias ls=gls` to use the GNU ls instead of the default ls. GNU ls usually comes with the `coreutils` package, so, e.g.,

- On macOS: `brew install coreutils`
- On FreeBSD: `pkg install coreutils`

Answer (score 0):

List with lines without columns:

```
ls -x
```

Using tr to avoid multiple lines output:

```
ls | tr "\n" " "
```

And to ensure to accurately force ascending order:

```
ls -v | tr "\n" " "
```

Some useful and essential information from [linux.org](https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/ls.html) about ls.